# How to use get() function vectorized when creating new columns in data.tables?

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I am trying to fit a distribution to my data from a data.table and create a new data.table which contains the date, the estimated parameters and the implied 75th percentiles. However, when I try to compute the 75th percentiles, I notice my code does not use the `sd` column. Please consider the following sample code:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

distribution <- 'norm'
dt <- data.table(Date = c('2012', '2013', '2014'),
                 mean = 1:3,
                 sd = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))

x <- rnorm(100, 1, 0.2)
# I'm trying to write code which not only allows distributions with mean and sd parameters.
paramNames <- names(fitdist(x, distr = distribution)$estimate)
qFunctionName <- eval(get(paste0('q',distribution)))
qName <- paste0('percentile', '75')

print(dt[, eval(qName) := qFunctionName(p = 0.75, get(paramNames))])

#    Date mean  sd percentile75
# 1: 2012    1 0.1      1.67449
# 2: 2013    2 0.2      2.67449
# 3: 2014    3 0.3      3.67449

dt[1, percentile75] == qnorm(0.75, mean = 1, sd = 0.1)
# > FALSE
dt[1, percentile75] == qnorm(0.75, mean = 1, sd = 1)
# > TRUE
```

Apparently, get() is not able to also consider the `sd` column. How can I alter the code so that it would take all the columns with column names saved in the `paramNames` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(fitdistrplus)

distribution <- 'norm'
dt <- data.table(Date = c('2012', '2013', '2014'),
    mean = 1:3,
    sd = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))

set.seed(0L)
x <- rnorm(100, 1, 0.2)
paramNames <- names(fitdist(x, distr = distribution)$estimate)
qFunctionName <- match.fun(paste0('q',distribution))
qName <- paste0('percentile', '75')

dt[, (qName) := do.call(qFunctionName, c(list(p=0.75), mget(paramNames)))][]
all.equal(dt[1, percentile75], qnorm(0.75, mean = 1, sd = 0.1))
```

In a nutshell, `get` only returns the first when a vector is passed into `x`, hence you need `mget` (try `get(c("x", "y"))` where `y` is undefined).

And also you need `do.call` to construct and executes a function call.

And also dont use `==` to test on a double due to numeric stability issues. There are lots and lots of R questions on this.

Comment: Thanks so much! Good to know there is a `match.fun` function for these cases. I couldn't find it hence my cumbersome `eval(get())` method.